# How to break a code line in Lua

Tags: string, syntax, lua

Stupid question but I can't seem to find the answer. For example if I had this bit of Lua code:

```
print("<html code blabla>
   <more html><and its long so I want to break it up like this>")
```

I've tried using `\` and `/` at the end of the first line but it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible to do in Lua and if so how?

Comment: Are you trying to get the newline included in the string, or just continue the string as if it were declared on one long line?

Comment: [The escape sequence '\z' skips the following span of white-space characters, including line breaks; it is particularly useful to break and indent a long literal string into multiple lines without adding the newlines and spaces into the string contents.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print("<html code blabla>\z
       <more html><and its long so I want to break it up like this>")
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that this is lua 5.2 only. For 5.1 you would need/want to use a long string.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Both modern versions of vanilla Lua (5.2+) and LuaJIT (2.0.0+) support `\z`.  I don't think someone still using old plain Lua 5.1 where `\z` is not working.

Comment: Plenty of people are still using lua 5.1.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Do you mean they are using Lua 5.1 inside game engines such as WOW or Minecraft?

Comment: Since [Lua for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) hasn't updated to 5.2 yet and there are a lot of users of that simple to install package I expect there are still a fair number of Lua 5.1 users. There are still 5.0 and earlier users due to the ease of embedding Lua in other programs as well. A portable way to make multi-line string literals is to use the `[[...]]` long string notation, but that will include newlines in the string. You can also use string concatenation of multiple quoted literals, and the compiler will usually do the concatenation at compile time.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff lua gets embedded in things, many things have yet to update. With 5.3 in the works I imagine many things won't bother updating anytime soon if they hadn't already. In general assuming that people update quickly (especially across major versions with hugely breaking changes) is a bad assumption.

Comment: @EtanReisner - So, what Lua versions must be covered by answers on SO questions tagged "lua"?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That is a very good question. I'd probably argue that any version should be acceptable as long as it is indicated and with the obvious understanding that the less common a version is in current usage the less likely it is that someone will get a useful answer.

Comment: @RBerteig "compiler will usually do the concatenation at compile time": The standard Lua implementations (5.0, 5.2.2) do not do that. I depended on that behavior in an embedded system I worked on.